# Bash script returns permission denied message

Tags: bash, shell-script, chmod

When I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# internet-status.sh
# ==================

now=$(date +%F)
cmd_output=$(nc -dzvw1 8.8.8.8 443 2>&1)
logfile_string=$("[$now] $cmd_output")
logfile=$("$HOME/internet.log")
$logfile_string >> "$logfile"
```

it returns:

`/home/xxxx/internet.log: Permission denied`

I've run chmod u+x on internet-status.sh

The permissions are:

`-rw-rw-rw- internet.log` and 
`-rwxrw-r-- internet-status.sh`

Answer (score 2):

`$(...)` is a *command substitution*.

Whereas `date +%F` and `nc -dzvw1 8.8.8.8 443 2>&1` are commands, `"[$now] $cmd_output"` and `"$HOME/internet.log"` are just strings - and should be assigned as such:

```
logfile_string="[$now] $cmd_output"
logfile="$HOME/internet.log"
```

You then presumably want to `echo` the string to the file:

```
echo "$logfile_string" >> "$logfile"
```